# How get userPassword attribute from LDAP using Spring and Java

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

i want to get userPassword attribute from ldap using spring in java.

of course this not work:

```
context.getStringAttribute("userPassword");
```

If i try:

```
context.getObjectAttribute("userPassword");
```

i can get this attribute..but now from Object how i can get the hash password?

Comment: What kind of `Object` is it?  It's not likely it's `java.lang.Object`.  You should find out what kind of `Object` it really is and cast it to that type.

Comment: i don't know how i can get this attribute.. maybe the method getObjectAttribute is wrong..the userPassword attribute is like: userPassword: {MD5}AFxCqn99F5XK4RfSxu1Ldg==

Comment: You said `getObjectAttribute("userPassword")` returns you an `Object`, that sound's right.  If you have a debugger see what *kind* of object it is, or if not, `System.out.println(theObject.getClass().getName())` to find out what kind of `Object` it is.  Once you know, just cast it to the right type.

Comment: if i try your code i have print this: [B

Comment: That sounds like a `byte[]` array, so try this:  `String pwHash = new String((byte[]) theObject);`, this is casting the `Object` to a `byte[]` array and creating a new `String` from it (using the default encoding)

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this at all. You should be getting the LDAP server to compare the password to what the user entered, either by attemping a bind or by searching with the user credentials as the search parameters.

Comment: @EJP yes i know but my problem was how retrieve this attribute userPasswor for one user of course..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like `context.getObjectAttribute("userPassword")` returns an `Object` so you just need to identify what it is.

Based on the comments it was a `byte[]` array which was representing a `String`, so you can basically do this:

```
Object o = context.getObjectAttribute("userPassword");
byte[] bytes = (byte[]) o;
String hash = new String(bytes);
```